# ReactJS save submission from input for other API calls

Tags: node.js, forms, reactjs, variable-assignment

I'm working on a React web app and need to save the input from a form submission to reuse in multiple API calls.

I'm able to use the input initially to make an API call and display results but I'm not able to save that input from the form to make another call.  Ultimate purpose is to give the user the ability after entering the search term to tap a button to filter responses by another criteria.

I've noted below what I'd like to do in the code but isn't working:

```
class Search extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        data: [],
        inputValue: '',
    };
  }

  onInitialSearch = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    ////this value is what I use in the initial API call which is working
    const { value } = this.input;

    ////this is what I'd like to be able to do but isn't working
    //this logs nothing in console
    this.setState({ inputValue : this.input}), function () {
        console.log("inputValue  is ",this.state.inputValue);
    };

    if (value === '') {
        return;
    }
    this.fetchStories(value);
  }

  fetchStories = (value) => {
    axios.get(getNews(value))
        .then(response => {
            this.setState({data: response.data.articles});
        })
  }

   render() {
     return (
            <div className="page">
                <div className="App-search">
                    <form type="submit" onSubmit={this.onInitialSearch}>
                        <input type="text" ref={node => this.input = node} />
                        <button type="submit">Search</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <List list={this.state.data} />
                 </div>
            </div>
    );
}
}

export default Search
```

Comment: Why don't you take search state out into another component, lets say `SearchContainer`, then you can add your filters and search form as children and pass down the state? This way even if you remove search field child completely your state is still persisted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the input field controlled.

```
<input type="text" onChange={(e) => this.setState({inputValue: e.target.value})} value={this.state.inputValue} />
```

And `onInitialSearch` function can use the value from state, without using refs. The value will not be removed after submit, so you can reuse it when needed.

For more on controlled and uncontrolled components, see: https://medium.com/@peter.yun.kim/controlled-and-uncontrolled-input-values-in-react-907119cc98d4